# How to use nuget library SimpleHelpers.FileEncoding on c# on VScode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, nuget

`dotnet add package SimpleHelpers.FileEncoding`

> [SimpleHelpers.FileEncoding](https://github.com/khalidsalomao/SimpleHelpers.Net/blob/master/docs/fileencoding.md)

`dotnet run`

it shows:

> C:\Users\user\Downloads\c2\Program.cs(1,7): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SimpleHelpers' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\user\Downloads\c2\c2.csproj]

---

Program.cs:

```cs
using SimpleHelpers.FileEncoding;

namespace c2;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        var encoding = FileEncoding.DetectFileEncoding (@"D:\b\big5\LanTingJiXu_big5.txt");
    }
}
```

c2.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="SimpleHelpers.FileEncoding" Version="1.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

---

update the error message.

Comment: Which line of code is throwing this exception? What's the full stack trace? Make sure you include that sort of information in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this package was authored to use the `content` folder with a .cs.pp file transform that were previously rendered and copied to the project folder for projects using `packages.config` to reference NuGet packages.

This is no longer supported for SDK-style projects which use `PackageReference`. The package author would need to switch to (or add) `contentFiles` to support `PackageReference` or create a pre-built binary (`.dll` file).